# Linux: How to find who issued a specific command while using root account?

Tags: linux, centos6

There's a Linux CentOS 6.5 server in my company which many employees have access to.

More than that, even though it's a known bad-practice, some people are working on the server using root account.

Today, a whole home folder of one of the users had been chmod'ed 777 by someone using the root account.

Is there a way for me to find which IP was logged on while the command was issued? and is there a way for me to prove that this IP was the one responsible for the change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can look into `/var/log/secure` to get login times. If there was only one user at the time, it's a strong *indication* he was the culprit (but not necessary a proof). If there where more users logged in, you can't identify the offending IP this way.

With users sharing a username, even the auditing subsystem won't help you much, I guess.

Having shared root access in an environment where not everyone is fully trusted (and admits it if he screwed up) is an extremely bad idea.

Comment: This is one of the many things that `sudo` is great at.  Doesn't help the OP this time, though.

Comment: I totally agree with you, but this server is not one of the ones I manage so I have no say regarding it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try implementing sudosh - http://sourceforge.net/projects/sudosh/

It acts like a VCR, you can see the commands the people ran and who exactly ran it. Hope this helps.